# total derivative of determinant function

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation, determinant

Let $\phi:M_2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the determinant function. Identify $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ with $\mathbb{R}^4$ by $\begin{bmatrix} x & y\\z & w\end{bmatrix}\mapsto (x,y,z,w)$.

Then (following convention of Munkres' Calculus on manifolds), for $A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}\leftrightarrow (a,b,c,d)$, the matrix of the total detivative of $\phi$ at $A$ is the $1\times 4$ matrix $$D_A=\begin{bmatrix} d & -c & -b & a\end{bmatrix}$$
Hence the derivative map is given by 
$$\begin{bmatrix} p\\q\\r\\s\end{bmatrix} \mapsto D_A\begin{bmatrix} p\\q\\r\\s\end{bmatrix}=dp-cq-br+sa$$

On the other hand, it was asked in a problem to show that the derivative of determinant map is by $D_A(B)=\mbox{Tr}((\mbox{adj}\,A)^tB)$. But 
$$
\mbox{Tr}((\mbox{adj}\,A)^tB)= \mbox{Tr}\Big{(} \begin{bmatrix}d & -c \\-b & a\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}p & q\\r & s\end{bmatrix}\Big{)}=dp-cr-bq+as.$$

So the answers are looking different!Can one point out my mistake and also suggest standard book reference for the result of total derivative of determinant map?

Comment: If you consider the determinant as a multilinear function of the columns of a matrix, there's a standard formula for its derivative, namely $D(\det)_{(a_1, \dots, a_n)}(h_1, \dots, h_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \det(a_1, \dots, a_{i-1}, h_i, a_{i+1}, \dots, a_n)$, where each $a_i, h_i \in \Bbb{R}^n$. For example, I believe Spivak has an exercise regarding derivatives of multilinear maps. My favourite reference though is Henri Cartan's book, Differential Calculus (see pages 29-30 for example, which talks about derivatives of bilinear and multilinear maps).

Answer (score 1):

$$\mbox{adj}\,A = \begin{bmatrix}d & -c \\ -b & a\end{bmatrix}$$
while
$$\mbox{adj}\,A^t = \begin{bmatrix}d & -b \\ -c & a\end{bmatrix}$$
It is the latter that is used in the formula.